# my C function is modifying a char array it shouldn't because it's deliberately out of scope

Tags: arrays, c, pass-by-reference, c-strings, palindrome

I wrote a little program in C that checks if a word of phrase is a palindrome.  One function does the checking after calling another function to remove the spaces in a phrase.  The app first asks the user to enter a word or phrase. Then it strips out the spaces in a separate function then evaluates the function to see if its a palindrome and return a bool...
The printf statements use the original string (or should) but the resulting printf uses the modified string instead. I don't see where is gets it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPalindrome(char string[]);
char* stripSpaces(char *noSpace);

int main(void)
{
    char usrStr[250];


    printf("Please enter a string and I will check if it is a palindrome...");
    scanf( "%250[^\n]", usrStr);
    
    printf("\n");
    isPalindrome(usrStr) ? printf("\"%s\" is a palindrome", usrStr) : printf("\"%s\" is not a palindrome", usrStr);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(char* string)
{
    char* newStr = stripSpaces(string);
    
    int middle = strlen(newStr) / 2;
    int len = strlen(newStr);

    for(int x = 0; x < middle; x++)
        if(newStr[x] != newStr[len - x - 1])
            return false;  
    // Check first char againse last char - then 2 char against 2nd last char and so on until mismatch found.
    // If no mismatch then the string is a palindrome
    
    return true;
}

char* stripSpaces(char *noSpace)
{
    int length = strlen(noSpace);
    int count = 0;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++)
    {
        if(noSpace[idx] != ' ')
        {
            noSpace[count] = noSpace[idx];
            count++;
        }
    }
    noSpace[count] = '\0';

    return noSpace;

}
```

Any thoughts?
Cheers
Charles

I tried making usrStr a const to no avail. I expected usrStr to not get modified as it is out of scope in the stripSpaces function.

Comment: Passing an array or pointer to a function does make a copy of the pointer but not the data. You're seeing the original modified because that is exactly what is happening. If you want to preserve the original you'll need to make a copy.

Comment: ...but there's no need to modify the data to solve this, and thus no need to copy. Just use two indexes or pointers, and compare the outermost non-space you haven't compared yet until 1) they are different (return false), or 2) The right index/pointer becomes less-than-or-equal to the left index/pointer (return true).

Comment: IMO, using the ternary operator to call one of two invocations of `printf()` is an abuse of the operator.  Use `if`/`else`.

Comment: Please revise the above to clarify the question.  "Any thoughts?" is not answerable to the standards we use (objective, specific etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`noSpace` is a pointer. If you change a pointer it will change out of scope too.

for a new string you can use `malloc`

```c
char* stripSpaces(char *noSpace)
{
    int length = strlen(noSpace);
    char *ret = malloc( length );
    int count = 0;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++)
    {
        if(noSpace[idx] != ' ')
        {
            ret[count++] = noSpace[idx];
        }
    }
    ret[count] = '\0';

    return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to its first element. While you've made a copy of the *pointer* the data it points to is the same.

If you wish to *not* modify the original string, you need to *copy* its contents and work on the copy rather than the original. The [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function makes this very simple.

```
char* stripSpaces(char *noSpace)
{
    int length = strlen(noSpace);
    char * str_copy = strdup(noSpace);
    int count = 0;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++)
    {
        if(str_copy[idx] != ' ')
        {
            str_copy[count] = str_copy[idx];
            count++;
        }
    }
    str_copy[count] = '\0';

    return str_copy;
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that this is dynamically allocating memory, so you have to de-allocate when you're done.

```
bool isPalindrome(char* string)
{
    char* newStr = stripSpaces(string);
    
    int middle = strlen(newStr) / 2;
    int len = strlen(newStr);

    for(int x = 0; x < middle; x++)
        if(newStr[x] != newStr[len - x - 1]) {
            free(newStr);
            return false; 
        }
    
    free(newStr);
    return true;
}
```

You should also check that `strdup` succeeded in allocating memory. If it fails, it will return a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Look for example at your own declarations of the function `isPalindrome`

```
bool isPalindrome(char string[]);
```

and

```
bool isPalindrome(char* string)
//...
```

These function declarations are equivalent. The complier adjusts a parameter having an array type to a parameter having a pointer type to the element type of the array.

On the other hand, an array used as an argument expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Within the function `isPalindrome`

```
bool isPalindrome(char* string)
{
    char* newStr = stripSpaces(string);
    //...
```

you are explicitly passing to the function `stripSpaces` the pointer to the first element of the original array `usrStr`. So the function `stripSpaces` using this pointer and the pointer arithmetic in the expression `noSpace[count]` that is equivalent to the expression `*( noSpace + count )` can change any element of the original array.

In C passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it to a function means passing the object by reference because using the pointer you can change the original object by means of dereferencing the pointer.

As for other characteristics of your code then for example instead of this used format string

```
scanf( "%250[^\n]", usrStr);
```

you have to write

```
scanf( "%249[^\n]", usrStr);
```

Otherwise if the user indeed will enter `250` characters then the function `scanf` will write the terminating zero character `'\0'` outside the array that results in undefined behavior.

The function `strlen` has the unsigned integer return type `size_t`. So you have to write for example

```
size_t len = strlen(newStr);
```

instead of

```
int len = strlen(newStr);
```

The function `isPalindrome` shall not change a passed to it string. So its single parameter should be declared with qualifier `const` like

```
bool isPalindrome( const char* string);
```

The approach when an auxiliary array is created to store a string without blanks is inefficient and unsafe. The function shall not require an additional memory to check whether a string is a palindrome.

Also pay attention to that you should process also tab characters `'\t'` that also can separate words in a string.

I would declare and define the function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPalindrome( const char *s )
{
    const char *left = s, *right = s + strlen( s );

    while (true)
    {
        while (isblank( ( unsigned char )*left )) ++left;
        while (right != left && isblank( ( unsigned char )*--right ));

        if (left == right || *left != *right) break;

        ++left;
    }

    return left == right;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = " 1 ";
    printf( "\"%s\" is %spalindrome.\n", s, isPalindrome( s ) ? "" : "not " );

    s = " 1 1 ";
    printf( "\"%s\" is %spalindrome.\n", s, isPalindrome( s ) ? "" : "not " );

    s = " 1 2 1 ";
    printf( "\"%s\" is %spalindrome.\n", s, isPalindrome( s ) ? "" : "not " );

    s = " 1 1 2 ";
    printf( "\"%s\" is %spalindrome.\n", s, isPalindrome( s ) ? "" : "not " );
}
```

The program output is

```
" 1 " is palindrome.
" 1 1 " is palindrome.
" 1 2 1 " is palindrome.
" 1 1 2 " is not palindrome.
```